# OWL reasoning in Prolog query from AllegroGraph Python API

Tags: python, prolog, triplestore, allegrograph

I noticed that in the AllegroGraph Python API tutorial [here](http://www.franz.com/agraph/support/documentation/3.2/python-tutorial.html#RDFS++%20Inference), whenever they want to use OWL reasoning they use the `conn.getStatements` method instead of issuing a Prolog or SPARQL query.  Is it possible to get triples inferred from the OWL reasoner by issuing a Prolog or SPARQL query instead of using the `conn.getStatements` method?  I tried a Prolog query:

`(select (?x ?y) (q ?x !ex:owned-by ?y))`

where I had defined owned-by as `owl:inverseOf ex:owns` and had the triple `ex:someone ex:owns ex:something` in my store, and I got no results.  I do get results from using `conn.getStatements`, so am I missing something essential in the Prolog query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you call setIncludeInferred on the query object returned from prepareTupleQuery before calling evaluate?

http://www.franz.com/agraph/support/documentation/v4/python-tutorial/python-API-40.html#Query%20Class

IncludeInferred is False by default. I believe valid values are false (no reasoning), "rdfs++" or True, and "restriction", as mentioned in the HTTP rest documentation for the infer http query parameter. The Python implementation just passes the value through.

http://www.franz.com/agraph/support/documentation/v4/http-protocol.html#header2-364

Comment: ah, that's what I was missing.  Thanks!